# What's the reason of engine roughness while leveling off from climb or recovering from stall?

Tags: propeller, piston-engine

I want to find out that if relative wind pressure can affect engine or not.

Comment: Float carbs can have issues from manuevering.  Some good reading [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_carburetor).  R/C planes also use exhaust pressure to keep positive pressure on the fuel tank and a flexible "clunk" tube to keep fuel line under the liquid level regardless of the attitude of the aircraft.

Comment: thanks alot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, except to the extent that dynamic pressure in the cowl affects the cooling rate.  That is, the engine cools off way faster with higher indicated speed than at low indicated speed.  On a climb, if anything the cylinders will be hot, so that's not really a cylinder cooling issue.

At the end of a climb it can be from mild spark plug fouling from a long run with a fully rich mixture.

In the case of stall recovery, the engine can cool down somewhat and stumble with a sudden application of power from both plug fouling and the lower cylinder temperatures. That's why on long descents at idle you are supposed to give periodic shots of power.

Roughness can also be from carburetor ice formation, induction leaks (lean cylinder), mag problems, spark plug problems (bad resistors - I recently had to replace my Champion plugs because 6 of 8 of them had over-the-limit resistance, causing very subtle rough running problems) or bad wires.

Comment: Thanks alot, my exact problem is that, when I level off rapidly from a climb or an unusual attitude, engine starts to fail or near failure and prop speed reduction is obvious then. But I don't have this problem when leveling off from descent.

Comment: It shouldn't do that all the time. It doesn't do it on my plane. You might have a carburation issue or an induction leak or something.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni only if you go zero or negative G. That will make the engine flood out and it will quit until you are back to positive G.

Comment: yeah exactly when i back to +g problem is solved. but may i ask you to explain alittle abou engine flooding that you mentioned there?

Comment: When you go zero G, the float and valve in the carb "floats"' it stops regulating fuel level in the bowl. It's exactly like the float valve in a toilet tank.  The fuel sitting in the bottom of the float bowl no longer has gravity to limit what can be sucked through the metering port by the engine's vacuum, so the mixture ratio gets all screwed up and the engine dies from overrich.  You should try running leaned out while doing the maneuvers and see what happens.  Running leaned is fine as long as you don't run it at 100% power while leaned.

Comment: Thank you so much ❤️